# Handling addition of two binary numbers

Tags: c++, time-limit-exceeded

This code is for handling addition of two binary numbers, which can be as long as 100,000 bits... and up to 500,000 queries are performed.

High-level pseudocode:

1. First input `N`: number of bits in binary number `A` and `B`.
2. Second input `Q`: number of queries to be performed.
3. Next `N` inputs: 0/1s ... bits for `A`
4. Next `N` inputs: 0/1s ... bits for `B`
5. Next `Q` inputs are one of the following:

   1. `set_a INDEX VALUE`: as a result I set `a[INDEX] = VALUE`
   2. `set_b INDEX VALUE`: as a result I set `b[INDEX] = VALUE`
   3. `get_c INDEX`: as a result I print `c[INDEX]` where `C = A+B` (binary addition, like `100 + 101 = 1001`)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>  // For pair
#include <iterator> // For iterator, bidirectional_iterator_tag, reverse_iterator
#include <climits>  // For CHAR_BIT, ULONG_MAX
using namespace std;


class VanEmdeBoasTree {};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  int n, q;
  char c;
  bool a[100005] = {0}, b[100005] = {0};
  VanEmdeBoasTree equals;
  cin>>n;
  cin>>q;

  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>c;
    if(c=='1')
      a[n-i-1] = true;
  }
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>c;
    if(c=='1')
      b[n-i-1] = true;
    if(a[n-i-1] == b[n-i-1]){
      equals.insert(n-i-1);
    }
  }

  string query;
  int index, val, lastval;
  for(int i=0;i<q;i++){
    cin>>query;
    cin>>index;
    if(query[4] == 'a'){
      cin>>val;
      if(a[index] != val){
        a[index] = val;
        if(a[index] == b[index]){
          equals.insert(index);
        }else{
          equals.erase(index);
        }
      }
    }else if(query[4] == 'b'){
      cin>>val;
      if(b[index] != val){
        b[index] = val;
        if(a[index] == b[index]){
          equals.insert(index);
        }else{
          equals.erase(index);
        }
      }
    }else if(query[4] == 'c'){
      int final = 0;
      if(index == n){
        if(equals.size() > 0){
          VanEmdeBoasTree::const_iterator it = equals.predecessor(index+1); 
          if(it!=equals.end() && a[*it] == 1){
            final = 1;
          }
        }
      }else{
        final = (a[index] + b[index])%2;
        if(equals.size() > 0){
          VanEmdeBoasTree::const_iterator it = equals.predecessor(index); 
          int last = -1;
          if(it != equals.end())
            last = *it;
          if( last!=-1 && index!=0 && it!=equals.end() &&  a[last] == 1){
            final = 1-final;
          }
        }
      }
      cout<<final;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

My solution is not fast enough as the Judge says "time out" after some test cases.

Comment: Can you link the online judge for this problem?

Comment: @WinstonEwert its the same one posted in one of the issues raised in  meta.codereview.stackexchange.com by you. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profile and you will find your bottlenecks, you can do that with gprof under gcc/g++. You have to set the `-g -pg` on compile and then run your program like you would do normally. It will then produce a gmon.out file which you can open with `gprof main gmon.out` (assuming main is the name of your executable).

It will show you, in which functions your program spends most of the time.

Comment: The code in is C++ and gcc wont compile it, i tired what you said with g++ but no gmon.out was created.

Comment: @Pheonix Oh, I forgot, you have to add `-g`.

Comment: @Pheonix: The gmon.out is generated after you run the program.

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved this problem (using a different technique then you)

Things I learned that you might find useful:

1. There is a lot of input for the test cases. I found that I was spending the bulk of my time just reading in the input. However, this didn't didn't show up in the output of gprof
2. I had to construct test cases with pathalogical natures to find the performance issues with my solution.

Comment: congratulations... but on the other hand, i am struggling a lot, i changed quiet a few things, not using stl::map anymore, my own testcases are coming fine, tested with hundreds of them now, but wrong answer after #5... and its been 2 days with that :( am out of test cases

Comment: @Pheonix, if you share the latest version of the code, I'll see if I can pinpoint where yours fails

Comment: i updated my code in the question, removed the implementation of VanEmdeBoasTree from code, http://www.keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=van-emde-boas-tree .. i dont get timeout (thanks to van-emde-boas), but wrong answer.

Comment: additionally, there is one more implementation with some changes, which i made to make testing easier, it sets random bits and A/B and prints all A, B, C... so i see if result is matching or not, if u wish i will post that code too.

Comment: @Pheonix, your code doesn't print a newline after all the bits. Other then that, I haven't found a case where my version differs.

Comment: They want it all in a single line, isn't it ? did i miss something ? i am feeling stupid, `Output must be placed in a single line.` that's what i still see there, :( i am really confused now !

Comment: @Pheonix, you need a newline after all the bits, i.e. one at the very end of your program.